# Drawing continuous lines on Xcode/Unity

Tags: sprite-kit, game-maker, unity3d-2dtools

I am making a app which draws continuous lines like a snake using Unity and SKSpriteKit (Obj-C) in Xcode (I’m making 2 versions of the same app in both):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qA1zk.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/484kj.png

http:// i.stack.imgur.com/QTEkC.png (Apologies for the image posts. I can't post an image/more than 2 links)

If you’ve ever heard of a game called Curve Fever, what I’m doing here is quite similar to it. I’m controlling the direction of the end of the line with the arrowkeys, whilst the end of the line automatically moves forward every frame creating an image like the one above.

However, from the 3 screenshots above, it is quite obvious that my program isn’t very efficient - every frame, I add a circle sprite to the SKScene in the place where my moving sprite is, which is why, after a while, there are over 1000 nodes on the screen, and the energy impact/memory/cpu is very high… Not ideal.

So now I’m looking for better ways of drawing the line on the screen without drawing thousands of nodes.

A while ago, a friend talked to me about how he made a similar app in GameMaker (which I have no knowledge of how to use). When I asked him how he rendered the line, he said he created something called a “surface”, and when anything moved on that surface, the old position of the sprite would still stay there - which would create lines if a circle moved across the surface.

He was rather vague about this, and I tried to do some research later, but with no success. I couldn’t find anything relevant about continuous lines, surfaces and GameMaker, Xcode or Unity.

If someone could come up with a solution like my friend was talking about, for Xcode/Unity - preferably both (or if someone could tell me what he was talking about for GameMaker), then I’d be grateful, as this would optimise my game and reduce the severe lags I get after around 30 seconds.

Also, I’d be grateful if anyone could suggest alternative solutions to this, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using GameMaker but I have no knowledge of Xcode or Unity. I can't help you directly but I can explain GameMaker surfaces.

Surfaces in GM are objects where you can draw on instead of directly drawing on the screen. Later you can draw the surface to the screen. The main advantage of it is that you can store a surface and for example draw it again in another tick, while the screen is redrawn in every tick, or that you can change it over time.

Surfaces are basically just bitmaps where you draw on. That means it wouldn't be hard to do the same in any other environment. Most other libraries/APIs call it canvas.

In your example you would draw one circle to the bitmap in each tick and then draw the whole bitmap to the screen.

A related topic is destructible terrain as it is discussed here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6721/implementing-a-2d-destructible-landscape-like-worms